# Convert dataframe column to a comma separated value in spark scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a Dataframe as below

[image: My dataframe]
I want the output to be like

[image: Expected output]

Basically it should group according to the TPID and give the personal role in a comma seperated value as shown in second figure.

Comment: next time, please copy/paste the output rather than adding images to the question

Comment: I tried but i was facing some format issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use these functions:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//read data in inputDF
inputDF.groupBy("Tpid")
      .agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list("PersonalRole")).alias("PersonalRole"))
      .select(col("Tpid"), col("PersonalRole"))
```